# Active Directory File Share with Security Group Cross Domain

Tags: active-directory, cross-domain

I have a server A in Active Directory domain D1.myschool.edu.au  which is offering a file share
only to workstations W1,W2,W3.

Workstations W1,W2,W3 have joined Active Directory domain D2.myschool.edu.au.

There is no trust between the domain D1.myschool.edu.au & domain D2.myschool.edu.au.
D1.myschool.edu.au & domain D2.myschool.edu.au are in separate forests.

Would this work for file share on A.D1.myschool.edu.au only to workstations W1,W2,W3:
1. Create a global security group mypcs containing workstations W1,W2,W3
   in D2.myschool.edu.au
2. Create a sigon D2.myschool.edu.au\me with AD admin access
3. In the file share on A, Security tab->Share Permissions->Add
       D2.myschool.edu.au\mypcs
       When I hit "Check Names" would I enter credentials for D2.myschool.edu.au\me?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

> offering a file share only to workstations W1,W2,W3

I know you can add a computer to NTFS permissions, but I don't entirely know how that works in practice. Usually you add only user objects or groups with users to permissions. But in your case, none of that would work anyway since there's no trust between the domains. (Your step 3 wouldn't work - you can't grant permissions to an untrusted domain)

The only way to allow make this "just work" is to allow access to `Everyone`, but I'm sure you don't want to do that.

Since there is no trust between the domains, whichever users are going to be accessing the shares would be prompted for credentials when attempting to access the share. They would have to provide credentials on the D1 domain. Those credentials could be stored by Windows for future use, so they would only have to provide those credentials the first time (as long as the Group Policy hasn't disabled that feature).